# Problem with First-Order nonlinear Differential Equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I am trying to derive an analytical expression for a solution to the following differential equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} - Be^{-y} = \cos(2x) + D,$$

where $B$ and $D$ are constants.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to how this can be done? If it cannot be solved analytically, is there an approximation that can be made (e.g. power series expansion) to allow an approx. analytical expression to be derived? I am not interested in solving this problem numerically.

Thank You

Comment: I think you've misread the equation, it is e^-y , not e^-x .

Comment: Yes, you are right, my mistake. I deleted my original comment.

Comment: Can you bring it to the form $u_x+F(x)G(u)=0$ by defining $y_x=u_x+\sin(2x)+D$?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, let \begin{align*}
y &= u + \frac 12 \sin(2x) + Dx \\
\implies \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} &= \frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} + \cos(2x) + D.
\end{align*}
Thus the differential equation becomes
$$\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} + \cos(2x) + D  - B \exp\left(-u - \frac 12 \sin(2x) - Dx\right) = \cos 2x + D,$$
and so \begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx} &= B e^{-u} e^{- \frac 12\sin (2x) - Dx} \\
\int e^u \; \mathrm du &= \int Be^{-\frac 12 \sin(2x) - Dx} \; \mathrm dx \\
u &= \ln \left( \int Be^{-\frac 12 \sin(2x) - Dx} \; \mathrm dx\right) \\
y &= \ln \left( \int Be^{-\frac 12 \sin(2x) - Dx} \; \mathrm dx\right) + \frac 12 \sin (2x) + Dx.
\end{align*}
The integral on the right is not elementary, so we expand around $x=0$ as a Taylor series. Recall the standard series \begin{align*}
e^x &= 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + O\left(x^4\right), \text{ and} \\
\sin(2x) &= (2x) - \frac{(2x)^3}{6} + O\left(x^5\right).
\end{align*}
Hence, $$- \frac 12 \sin (2x) - Dx = -(D+1)x + \frac 23 x^3 + O\left(x^5\right),$$
and so
\begin{align*}
\exp\left(-\frac 12 \sin(2x) - Dx\right) &= 1 + \left(-(D+1)x + \frac 23 x^3 + O\left(x^5\right)\right) \\
&\phantom{==} + \frac 12 \left(-(D+1)x + \frac 23 + O\left(x^5\right)\right)^2 \\
&\phantom{==} + \frac 16 \left(-(D+1)x + \frac 23 + O\left(x^5\right)\right)^3 + O\left(x^4\right) \\
&= 1 - (D+1)x + \frac 23 x^3 + \frac 12 (D+1)^2 x^2 - \frac 16(D+1)x^3 + O\left(x^4 \right) \\
&= 1 - (D+1)x + \frac 12 (D+1)^2 x^2 + \frac 13\left(2 - \frac 12(D+1)\right)x^3 + O\left(x^4\right).
\end{align*}
We could also have deduced this series by repeated differentiation.

Returning to the original problem,
\begin{align*}
y &= \ln\left( \int \left(B- B(D+1)x + \frac 12 B(D+1)^2 x^2 + \frac 13 B \left(2 - \frac 12 (D+1)^3\right)x^3 +O\left(x^4\right)\right)\right) \\
&\phantom{$=$}+ \frac 12 \sin(2x) + Dx \\
&= \ln \left(C + Bx - \frac 12 B(D+1)x^2  + \frac 16 B(D+1)^2 x^3 + \frac{1}{12}B \left(2 - \frac 12 (D+1)^3\right)x^4 + O\left(x^5\right)\right) \\
&\phantom{$=$}+ \frac 12 \sin(2x) + Dx.
\end{align*}
Feel free to expand to more terms if you so desire!

Comment: Thanks for replying kipf - I have followed everything as far as the Taylor Series expansion  of Be^(-0.5sin(2x) - Dx) . Could you share more on how you completed this expansion?

Comment: @PikaPika An explanation of the Taylor series has been added now. The old one was actually wrong so hopefully it's all correct now!

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} - Be^{-y} = \cos(2x) + D,$$
$$u(x)=e^y(x)\quad\implies\quad y'=\frac{u'}{u}= \frac{B}{u} + \cos(2x) + D$$
$$u'(x)=(\cos(2x)+D)u(x)+B$$
This is a first order linear ODE. Solving it with usual method leads to :
$$u(x)=B\,e^{D\,x+\frac12 \sin(2x)}\int e^{-D\,x-\frac12 \sin(2x)}dx$$
The arbitrary constant is included into the undefined integral.

The integral cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. So the above result is the analytic form of solution with a function defined by an integral.

Approximate solutions could be expressed on the form of series from the integral expansion.